# PHP Developing a composer package under vendor of the main project

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I have a main php project that needs a php component developed by me, that i intend to reuse in other projects, the component is in the main project vendor directory.
However pushing to Github the component, go to the main project, running composer update is time consuming.
In order to speed up the development of the component, is there a way to include the local component project into the main project?

Comment: If `composer update` is time consuming, then I believe that your internet connection is too slow. It doesn't take more than 5 minutes for me to update.

Comment: 5 minutes is too much, even 20 seconds, i may make change often

Comment: Yes composer is very slow. If you are only doing local dev you can disable the packagist repo which makes it install in the order of a few seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do local composer package development.

1. Create a `vendor-repo` folder next to the vendor folder.
2. Create a directory for the vendor and project name for example `vendor-repo/vendorname/packagename`
3. Create a git repo inside the `packagename` folder and build your composer package complete with `composer.json` etc.
4. Add your local repository to the main `composer.json` (the one that requires your package). You can also disable the packagist repo by adding the `"packagist": false` as per the example below. This will speed things up and is a good idea if you aren't using any packages from packagist.

`"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "vendor-repo/vendorname/packagename"
    },
    {
        "packagist": false
    }
]`

Then when you run `composer update` it will get your package from your local repo rather than needing to get it from GitHub.

Comment: thanks,yes the 'path' was what i was needing,i'll get deeper into the documentation for more advanced stuffs.

Comment: No worries @YvonHuynh glad you got it sorted. Composer documentation is really good :)

Comment: note:my package name is "vendorname/packagename",the url is "vendor-repo/vendorname" because when i clone from github my existing package it will create "packagename" folder

Comment: @YvonHuynh Usually I have the composer.json in the root of my package repos rather than inside a `packagename` directory but use whatever works for you :)

Comment: got it! one last thing about the semantic version,how does Composer read the tag inside the git repository?

Comment: @YvonHuynh sorry for the delayed reply. If you tag me into your comment (with @) it will email me :). To answer your question: it uses branch names prefixed with "dev-" so to use the master branch, specify the version as "dev-master"

Answer (score 0):

You can add the library directly inside your vendor folder, register the sources using the psr-0 or psr-4 autoload, dump the autoload classes and create a git repository inside the folder.

So you can use it as a library, and at the same time, you don't need to pull every update you do to test the library inside your project.

I don't know if it's a good approach, but symlinks didn't work for me and i still need to register the classes in the autoload.

Comment: that's an idea. I just wished i could reference a package as I do in c# in visual studio. I will try to just  run composer update once, then delete the entry relative to the package in composer.json so it will leave it on further updates.

Comment: You can also add that library our from vendor folder. A folder called "local_libs", for example, so the library sources would not be deleted after a successful composer update. Don't forget to change the autoload sources path.